# React-Redux: Action is Dispatched but Reducer is not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to check if my store is onboarded or not. for that, I'm making an API call through the redux to check it in the BE and if it's true I'll redirect it to the dashboard.  I'm able to get the data successfully from BE, and on success `checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess()` is called but in the reducer, the state is not updated with the `CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_SUCCESS` state in the reducer.

action.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './index';
import API from '../../api';

export const clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CLEAR_CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING,
  };
};

export const checkIsStoreOnboarded = (payload) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(checkIsStoreOnboardedInitiate());
    API.getAccountSettings(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            checkIsStoreOnboardedFailure(err);
        });
  };
};

const checkIsStoreOnboardedInitiate = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_START,
  };
};
const checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_SUCCESS,
    data: data,
  };
};
const checkIsStoreOnboardedFailure = (err) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_FAIL,
    data: err,
  };
};
```

reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  isError: false, 
  isDone: false,
  data: [],
  error: null,
};

const clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded = () => {
  return initialState;
};

const checkIsStoreOnboardedStart = (state) => {
  return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: null, isError: false };
};

const checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess = (state, action) => {
  return { ...state, data: action.data, isDone: true, isLoading: false };
};

const checkIsStoreOnboardedFailure = (state, action) => {
  return { ...state, error: action.data, isLoading: false, isError: true };
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.CLEAR_CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING:
      return clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded();
    case actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_START:
      return checkIsStoreOnboardedStart(state);
    case actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_SUCCESS:
      return checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess(state, action);
    case actionTypes.CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_FAIL:
      return checkIsStoreOnboardedFailure(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

actionTypes.js

```
export const CLEAR_CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING = 'CLEAR_CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING';
export const CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_START = 'CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_START';
export const CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_SUCCESS = 'CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_SUCCESS';
export const CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_FAIL = 'CHECK_IS_STORE_ONBOARDED_FOR_ONBOARDING_FAIL';
```

onboard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Crew from './Crew';
import Service from './Services';
import Address from './Address';
import { useStyles } from './css/index.css';
import Header from './header';
import Stepper from './stepper';
import { getStoreID } from '../../../utils';
import {
  clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded,
  checkIsStoreOnboarded,
} from '../../../store/actions/check-is-store-onboarded-for-onboarding'

import Loader from '../../../components/CircularProgressLoader';

const OnboardScreen = ({ 
  cookies,
  clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded,
  checkIsStoreOnboarded,
  checkIsStoreOnboardedData,
}) => {
 
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [width, isDesktop] = useWindowWitdh();
  const classes = useStyles(isDesktop);
  const store_id = getStoreID(cookies);


  useEffect(() => {
    checkIsStoreOnboarded({
      store_id,
    });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => () => clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded(), []);


  if(checkIsStoreOnboarded.isDone){
   <Redirect to='/dashboard'>
  }


  const updateStep = () => {
    const updatedStep = step + 1;
    setStep(updatedStep);
  };
  const onboardingScreenToRender = () => {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Crew />
        );
      case 1:
        return (
          <Service />
        );
      case 2:
        return <Address />;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Header isDesktop={isDesktop} />
      <div className={classes.contentOfContainer}>
          <div className={classes.titleHeader}>
            Onboarding
          </div>
        <Stepper stepNumber={step} setStepNumber={setStep} />
        {checkIsStoreOnboardedData.isLoading && <Loader />}
      </div>
    </div>
    // <OnboardLoader />
    );
  };
  

  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      ...ownProps,
      checkIsStoreOnboardedData: state.checkIsStoreOnboardedForOnboardingReducer
    };
  };
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      checkIsStoreOnboarded: (payload) => dispatch(checkIsStoreOnboarded(payload)),
      clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded: () => dispatch(clearCheckIsStoreOnboarded()),
    };
  };
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  )(withCookies(OnboardScreen));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `dispatch` your actions:

```js
export const checkIsStoreOnboarded = (payload) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(checkIsStoreOnboardedInitiate());
    API.getAccountSettings(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            // here
            dispatch(checkIsStoreOnboardedSuccess(response.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // and here
            dispatch(checkIsStoreOnboardedFailure(err)(;
        });
  };
};
```

That said: you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here - in modern Redux, all of that would probably be possible with 1/4 of the code. If you are just learning Redux, you are probably following a very outdated tutorial. Modern Redux does not require you to write action type strings or action creators and your reducers can contain mutable logic. Also, it does not use `connect` unless you are working with legacy class components (which you don't seem to be doing).

I really recommend you to read the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It has been of great help. Definitely, I will check out the modern redux and look forward to its implementation.

Comment: If it helped, please upvote & accept the answer :)